# v.bar is returning no results in my bokeh code

Tags: bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and Python and really not sure where I'm going wrong. I've created 4 dataframes english1 french1 german1 and spanish1.

To which I'm hoping to display in one bokeh graph to compare the to movie Genres based and those 4 languages..

This is my code][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEtjy.png)

[This is what I thought it would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDHsz.png)

[This is the german1 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgFFg.png)

Comment: Please never post code or data as images. They are not accessible and are not copy-paste-able. Please edit your post to include the code as ***properly formatted*** text. Also, make sure the code is a [***complete** minimal reproducing example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).